# Handling a Java Exception

Tags: java, exception

I can't figure out why my code isn't compiling correctly.. I can go through the code till it gets to the catch block.  It works, displaying the message, so I know it's catching the error.  However, it ends my program saying I have that same error at the same place.  I can't see what I am doing wrong.  Thanks for any help!!

```
class Verification {

String detAccess(String[] pL, String[] uL, String pass, String user) {
    int pos = 0;
    String access = "";
    try {
        for (int i=0; !user.equals(uL[i]); i++)
            pos++;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exec) {
        System.out.println("Username doesn't exist.");
        throw exec;
    }
    if(pass.equals(pL[pos])) {
        access = "MEMBER";
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password.");
        access = "DENIED";
    }

    return access;        
}
```

}

Comment: You're rethrowing the same error.  Who's catching it outside of your original "catch" block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your code to something like this:

```
int pos = -1;
...
for (int i=0;uL.length; i++)
{
    if(user.equals(uL[i])) { pos=i; break; }
}
...
if(pos==-1)
{
    // user not found
} else {
    // test the pass with pos as index
}
```

Comment: Ahhh!! Thank you! This fixed it and I didn't even have to use a try-catch block.  Again, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 7):

You are rethrowing the exception - `throw exec`;

Comment: Not the only issue in this code, at least if `pL` and `uL` are the same lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You're rethrowing the exception.

Another thing:

```
if(pass.equals(pL[pos])) {
    access = "MEMBER";
```

That will cause the exception to come up again even if you didn't rethrow it as it'll try to check the password list with a nonexistent index.

Answer (score 0):

you are throwing the exception back up. the point of handling the exception is that it **wron't** carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You're catching and rethrowing the exception; if you "handle it", you don't need to rethrow it.
2. You're using "Exception Handling" to manage the "normal control flow" through your program.  This is generally considered "bad style".  Can you not control your iteration, and determine that "you're done" by looking something else?

   UPDATE: i.e. nio's example

Answer (score 0):

The code *is* compiling correctly if you're able to run it.  As for the program ending in error, that's because you're throwing an exception:

```
throw exec;
```

You successfully *caught* the exception, but then you threw it again.  If nothing else catches it, the program will terminate in an error.